# Adding a class to textboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to use a jquery function to add a css class I have created to textboxes on a form. This class will change the border of the textbox to red, to indicate that there is an error in the textbox and that the user cannot submit until the error is fixed. Here is my current code:

```
function validateRequired() {
    var obj = $('.validate');
    var message = ""; 
    if (obj == null) {
        return message;
    }
    obj.each(function (index, elem) {
        if (elem.value == "") {
            message += splitCamelCase(elem.id);
            elem.attr("class", "error");
        }
    });

    return message;
}
```

For whatever reason, though I've used this in other points in the code to check and set attributes, I keep getting an error saying:

> The property or method (elem.attr("class", "error");) is unsupported.

How can I set the border of the textbox to red using jquery?

Comment: use .addClass insted of .attr. elem.addClass('error')

Comment: I've tried that as well, and it still blows up. I'll try it again, though, because I could have very well had a typo. EDIT: I did in fact try running it with .addClass again, and it gives the same error as .attr. Thanks for the input, though!

Comment: `elem` is the raw HTMLElement. You need to wrap it in `$(elem)`, or do `elem.className = 'error'`.

Comment: @kalley Why don't you make an aswer with that comment :) It is the good answer anyway.

Comment: FYI: HTML5 allows you to specify a custom validity checking function, and also defines the ':invalid' psuedo-class CSS selector which you can use for styling.  [setCustomValidity()](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity) ,  [:invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#validity-pseudos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elem` is the raw HTMLElement. You need to wrap it in `$(elem)`, or do `elem.className = 'error'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do instead of attribute:

```
    //...
    message += splitCamelCase(elem.id);
    $('this').addClass("error");

    //...
```